# T-SQL strip all non-alpha and non-numeric characters

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there a smarter way to remove all special characters rather than having a series of about 15 nested replace statements?

The following works, but only handles three characters (ampersand, blank and period).

```
select CustomerID, CustomerName, 
   Replace(Replace(Replace(CustomerName,'&',''),' ',''),'.','') as CustomerNameStripped
from Customer
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One flexible-ish way;

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnRemovePatternFromString](@BUFFER VARCHAR(MAX), @PATTERN VARCHAR(128)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @POS INT = PATINDEX(@PATTERN, @BUFFER)
    WHILE @POS > 0 BEGIN
        SET @BUFFER = STUFF(@BUFFER, @POS, 1, '')
        SET @POS = PATINDEX(@PATTERN, @BUFFER)
    END
    RETURN @BUFFER
END

select dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString('cake & beer $3.99!?c', '%[$&.!?]%')

(No column name)
cake  beer 399c
```

Comment: I see everyone is recommending functions.   
I like the idea of using a user-defined function, but then it has to go through change-control to get to the production environment.  There's no way to have an in-line function in the query, is there?
I'm not sure what language they are using to call the SQL query, maybe VBScript or Powershell, but now I'm thinking it's going to be a lot easier to do the stripping in that language.

Comment: Like a numbers table or calendar table, or functions that split or concatenate strings, a function that can do this type of thing is a handy module to have around. Even if it doesn't get there immediately, you should consider having these things in a utility database. I don't know that performing this in the code is always the best answer either, especially if multiple different applications need to do the same thing...

Comment: @Alex K., I like this solution better than my own.  I never did like having to examine the string one character at a time.  Do you have a way to replace extra spaces and special characters (cr/lf, tab) as well?

Comment: In case anyone is looking to only INCLUDE alphanumeric, you can just use this as the pattern with the above function: '%[^a-z0-9]%'

Answer (score 10):

Create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StripNonAlphaNumerics
(
  @s VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @p INT = 1, @n VARCHAR(255) = '';
  WHILE @p <= LEN(@s)
  BEGIN
    IF SUBSTRING(@s, @p, 1) LIKE '[A-Za-z0-9]'
    BEGIN
      SET @n += SUBSTRING(@s, @p, 1);
    END 
    SET @p += 1;
  END
  RETURN(@n);
END
GO
```

Then:

```
SELECT Result = dbo.StripNonAlphaNumerics
('My Customer''s dog & #1 friend are dope, yo!');
```

Results:

```
Result
------
MyCustomersdog1friendaredopeyo
```

To make it more flexible, you could pass in the pattern you want to allow:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StripNonAlphaNumerics
(
  @s VARCHAR(255),
  @pattern VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @p INT = 1, @n VARCHAR(255) = '';
  WHILE @p <= LEN(@s)
  BEGIN
    IF SUBSTRING(@s, @p, 1) LIKE @pattern
    BEGIN
      SET @n += SUBSTRING(@s, @p, 1);
    END 
    SET @p += 1;
  END
  RETURN(@n);
END
GO
```

Then:

```
SELECT r = dbo.StripNonAlphaNumerics
('Bob''s dog & #1 friend are dope, yo!', '[A-Za-z0-9]');
```

Results:

```
r
------
Bobsdog1friendaredopeyo
```

Comment: @Brian please don't edit other people's code without giving them some clue about what "didn't work" means. If you have a problem with the code, leave a comment, don't just edit it. I have no idea why your edit worked and the original "didn't work" but [I would never write code like that](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: You're right Aaron, looking back over this, that was very rude and I would surely be very annoyed if I were you as well. I rushed big time and I apologize. So to the point I was trying to make without using my words, @c is not defined in your code, so this doesn't run at all. I think I was reaching for a char-type of structure that some other languages have... I only needed the first function but the second part is probably impacted as well. Thanks for the code, it saved me some time. :)

Comment: I see you fixed it by eliminating @c. Thanks.

Comment: @Brian yes, once you *explained*, I understood your edit. Before then I honestly didn't. Please start with comments before editing code.

Comment: Understood. ;) We are all very protective of our work, although in my case anything written as far back as 2012 I wish I could erase entirely because I've learned so much since then... I imagine it will always be so. I apologize again for being indelicate. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I faced this problem several years ago, so I wrote a SQL function to do the trick.  [Here is the original article](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/pull-out-text-from-html-code) (was used to scrape text out of HTML).  I have since updated the function, as follows:

```
IF (object_id('dbo.fn_CleanString') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Dropping: dbo.fn_CleanString'
  DROP function dbo.fn_CleanString
END
GO
PRINT 'Creating: dbo.fn_CleanString'
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_CleanString 
(
  @string varchar(8000)
) 
returns varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Title:        CleanString
-- Date Created: March 26, 2011
-- Author:       William McEvoy
--               
-- Description:  This function removes special ascii characters from a string.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


declare @char        char(1),
        @len         int,
        @count       int,
        @newstring   varchar(8000),
        @replacement char(1)

select  @count       = 1,
        @len         = 0,
        @newstring   = '',
        @replacement = ' '



---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- M A I N   P R O C E S S I N G
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-- Remove Backspace characters
select @string = replace(@string,char(8),@replacement)

-- Remove Tabs
select @string = replace(@string,char(9),@replacement)

-- Remove line feed
select @string = replace(@string,char(10),@replacement)

-- Remove carriage return
select @string = replace(@string,char(13),@replacement)


-- Condense multiple spaces into a single space
-- This works by changing all double spaces to be OX where O = a space, and X = a special character
-- then all occurrences of XO are changed to O,
-- then all occurrences of X  are changed to nothing, leaving just the O which is actually a single space
select @string = replace(replace(replace(ltrim(rtrim(@string)),'  ', ' ' + char(7)),char(7)+' ',''),char(7),'')


--  Parse each character, remove non alpha-numeric

select @len = len(@string)

WHILE (@count <= @len)
BEGIN

  -- Examine the character
  select @char = substring(@string,@count,1)


  IF (@char like '[a-z]') or (@char like '[A-Z]') or (@char like '[0-9]')
    select @newstring = @newstring + @char
  ELSE
    select @newstring = @newstring + @replacement

  select @count = @count + 1

END


return @newstring
END

GO
IF (object_id('dbo.fn_CleanString') IS NOT NULL)
  PRINT 'Function created.'
ELSE
  PRINT 'Function NOT created.'
GO
```

Comment: I like the idea of using a user-defined function, but then it has to go through change-control to get to the production environment.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but still, might be handy for others.
Here's a quick and dirty (Which I've done inversely - stripping out non-numerics) - using a recursive CTE.
What makes this one nice for me is that it's an inline function - so gets around the nasty RBAR effect of the usual scalar and table-valued functions.
Adjust your filter as needs be to include or exclude whatever char types.

```
        Create Function fncV1_iStripAlphasFromData (
            @iString Varchar(max)
        )
        Returns 
        Table With Schemabinding
        As

            Return(

                with RawData as
                (
                    Select @iString as iString
                )
                ,
                Anchor as
                (

                    Select Case(IsNumeric (substring(iString, 1, 1))) when 1 then substring(iString, 1, 1) else '' End as oString, 2 as CharPos from RawData
                    UNION ALL
                    Select a.oString + Case(IsNumeric (substring(@iString, a.CharPos, 1))) when 1 then substring(@iString, a.CharPos, 1) else '' End, a.CharPos + 1
                    from RawData r
                    Inner Join Anchor a on a.CharPos <= len(rtrim(ltrim(@iString)))

                )

                Select top 1 oString from Anchor order by CharPos Desc

            )

Go

select * from dbo.fncV1_iStripAlphasFromData ('00000')
select * from dbo.fncV1_iStripAlphasFromData ('00A00')
select * from dbo.fncV1_iStripAlphasFromData ('12345ABC6789!&*0')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [SQL CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_CLR) you can use .NET regular expressions for this.

There is a third party (free) package that includes this and more - [SQL Sharp](http://www.sqlsharp.com/) .

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2017 and higher offers the translate function. It requires three arguments TRANSLATE( inputString, characters, translations )

There is a one-to-one relationship between the character list and the translation list. There are 30 possible characters to replace, so I replicated 30 spaces (instead of typing them). But since I don't want my return variable to contain spaces I wrapped the whole translate function in a replace function to remove them.

I should also point out that I declared @var to be varchar(8000) which is the largest possible value before moving to a varchar(max), which you should avoid unless you really need it. I would recommend you consider carefully the maximum size of the data you would be passing into this function and size the @var appropriately. I believe you could also use the nvarchar datatype.

Once you create the function, the way you would call it might look like the following two statements.

select dbo.AlphaNumericOnly('*&!Blah') as [no symbols]
The result would be just "Blah".

select col1, dbo.AlphaNumericOnly(col1) as [col1 no symbols] from someTable as t
The result would by a two column result set. The first column would be col1 unaltered, and the second column would be col1 without the special characters.

I hope this helps.

```sql
create function AlphaNumericOnly
(
    @var varchar(8000)
)
returns varchar(8000)
begin

    return replace(translate(@var, '`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\:;<,>.?/', replicate(' ', 30)), ' ', '')
end
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?