# Find or Strip Invalid characters from Database

Tags: sql, unicode, sql-server-2008-r2

We are using a database where the front end software has allowed the input of invalid characters. (I have no control or re-writing of the software.)

The types of characters are carriage returns, line breaks, �, ¶, basically anything that is not 0-9, a-z or standard punctuation causes us issues with the database and how we use the data.

I'm looking for a way to scan the entire database to identify these invalid codes and either display them as results or strip them out?

I had been looking at [This site](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html) wondering if there was a way of searching for a certain range? But I might be barking up the wrong tree.

I'm fairly new to SQL so be gentle with me, thanks.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: Microsoft SQL 2008 R2

Comment: If your SQL version supports `regular expressions`, it may have a special `class` for such (unprintable) characters.

Comment: I caution you on changing USER input data.  The handling of these special characters is UI problem.  It's obvious the database can handle their entry, the manipulation of this data is a UI problem, not a database one.  Think of this.  Is someone's last name "O'Brian" or "OBrian"  or "I don't think this is right" to " I dont think this is right"  now imagine that text is going out on marketing material, "OBrian, I dont think this is right"  values input by client matter.  You should NEVER change data on the client without their knowledge.  Prevent entry in the UI, don't change the saved data.

Comment: A mentioned previously I have No way or preventing at user input or changing input program to not accept these characters (at this time) all I can do is search the database and remove them. The reason is the data then moves to a second program that cannot handle these characters and this causes the process to fail.

Comment: If you are absolutely sure you want to do this then I doubt there is much point in searching for invalid characters in Sql before processing the data - whatever algorithm is checking the characters for the rogue values will have to process an entire field to establish there are no characters to replace ...  See what I mean ?

Comment: Then alter the method in which that second program pulls the data.  Again changing user input is not a good idea; especially if they can edit change it at a later date.

Comment: I have no control over the second program either, only the database.

Comment: Then you might as well crack on with a brute-force treatment on a char-by-char basis of all your data.  Is this feasible ?

Comment: No really, vast amount of data with lot and lot of tables, could be on that forever, was looking for anything that will search everything in one go (i know that will take a while to run) and give me a location of anything that's not a-z 1-0 or standard punctuation. Almost like a range search on Basic Latin.

Comment: Carrying this to an extreme: so decimal value 3.482 would now be 3482 right?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think to do this would be to write a stored procedure which uses system tables to get a list of all fields in the database/schema in question.  Have it exclude system tables (or only include those that are user defined) then dynamically write out SQL update statements based on the columns/tables found in the system table inquiries.  Using regular expressions or character removal like in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636045/t-sql-strip-all-non-alpha-and-non-numeric-characters)

The system tables in question are:

```
SELECT
 table_name,column_name
FROM
 information_schema.columns
```

Psudo code would be:

```
Get list of tables we want to do this for
For each table in list
get list of columns for table that have string data.
For each column in table
generate update statement to strip unwanted characters
--Consider writing out table, column key, before after values to history table. incase this 
has to be undone.
--Consider counter so I have an idea of what was updated
execute updatestatement
next column
next table
write out counter
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say

> the data then moves to a second program that cannot handle these
>   characters and this causes the process to fail.

I'm wondering if you can leave the unreadable data where it is and create a new column for changed data that's only populated if/when the 2nd process fails.  You'll still have to test every character of the data in the failed cell, but you wouldn't have to test every character of every row.  After you determine the updated text to process, you can call the 2nd process again with the updated value.