# replace multiple values at the same time - in order to convert a string to a number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to convert a varchar field to a number, however, there is a set of common characters inside that field that need to be removed in order for me to successfully convert it to numeric.

the name of the field is UKSellPrice1

I need to remove the following strings from UKSellPrice1 BEFORE converting it to numeric:

```
'.00'
'£'
'n/a'
'$'
'#N/A'
```

How can I get this done?

at the moment I have the following:
[image]

```
;WITH R0 AS (

SELECT StyleCode
      ,ColourCode       
      ,UKSellPrice1= CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.00',UKSellPrice1,1) > 0 
                          THEN REPLACE (UKSellPrice1,'.00','') 
                          ELSE UKSellPrice1 END
      ,UKSellPrice2
 FROM dbo.RangePlan
)
SELECT * 
FROM R0
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I can think of two approaches.

The first is to use a bunch of nested `replace()` statements:

```
select replace(replace(replace(col, '$', ''), '£', ''), 'n/a', '')
```

and so on.

The second is to find the first digit and try converting from there.  This requires complicated logic with `patindex()`.  Here is an example:

```
select cast(left(substring(col, patindex('%[0-9]%', col), 1000),
                 patindex('%[^0-9]%', substring(col, patindex('%[0-9]%', col), 1000)) - 1
                ) as int)
```

Answer (score 7):

You could do this. Create a function to strip a way the unwanted chars like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnRemovePatternFromString](@BUFFER VARCHAR(MAX), @PATTERN VARCHAR(128)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @POS INT = PATINDEX(@PATTERN, @BUFFER)
    WHILE @POS > 0 BEGIN
        SET @BUFFER = STUFF(@BUFFER, @POS, 1, '')
        SET @POS = PATINDEX(@PATTERN, @BUFFER)
    END
    RETURN @BUFFER
END
```

Then call the scalared function on the column with a pattern like this:

```
;WITH R0 AS (

SELECT StyleCode
      ,ColourCode       
      ,UKSellPrice1= CAST(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(UKSellPrice1,'%[£$#N/A.00]%') AS INT)
      ,UKSellPrice2
 FROM dbo.RangePlan
)
SELECT * 
FROM R0
```

Reference:

- [T-SQL strip all non-alpha and non-numeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636045/t-sql-strip-all-non-alpha-and-non-numeric-characters)

Comment: select dbo.[fnRemovePatternFromString]('120', '%[£$#N/A.00]%') gives 12 while one expects 120 so this solution should actually be used for single character replacements only

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [@Arion above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23218611/1501497) (thanks).
This is the equivalent of (n) number of REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE())) calls,
so just cleans up the code really nicely.
I've swapped out STUFF() for REPLACE() so it's slightly more general use than your example above.  Tested working (for my data sets), but I'm not a SQL guru, so YMMV.  Also, since it just uses REPLACE() under the hood this handles Replacement with any size string, not just 1 char (as with @Arion's example).

```
/*
.SYNOPSIS
    FIND/REPLACE MULTIPLE VALUES FROM A STRING

.DESCRIPTION
    Walk through the @FINDChars pattern, one character at a time.
    Do a find + REPLACE() on each of those characters in the string.

.EXAMPLE
    [dbo].[fnFindReplaceAnyMatch](MyColumnName, '(''")', '')
*/
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnFindReplaceAnyMatch](
    @BUFFER         VARCHAR(MAX), 
    @FINDChars      VARCHAR(128),
    @REPLACEChar    VARCHAR(128)
) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SingleCharPattern VARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE @PatternIndex INT = 0;
    WHILE @PatternIndex <= LEN(@FINDChars) BEGIN
        SET @SingleCharPattern = SUBSTRING(@FINDChars, @PatternIndex, 1);
        SET @BUFFER = REPLACE(@BUFFER, @SingleCharPattern, @REPLACEChar);
        SET @PatternIndex = @PatternIndex + 1;
    END
    RETURN @BUFFER
END
GO
```

Comment: Does the documentation style of the function supported by some documentation generator and if so, what is that documentation generator's name?