# New line delimited json file upload to bigquery error Code:3

Tags: google-bigquery

```
jobStatus: {
errorResult: {
code: 3
message: "Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1127; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details."
}
errors: [
0: {
code: 3
message: "Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1127; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details."
}
1: {
code: 3
message: "Error while reading data, error message: JSON processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1127; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error percent: 0"
}
2: {
code: 3
message: "Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 132601653: Parser terminated before end of string"
}]
jobState: "DONE"
```

This is line 1127 for the .json file

```
{"id":"xxx","ContextId":"xxx","dueAt":"2023-01-26T05:59:59.000Z","title":"1\/25 MATH: *LOCATION CHANGE* Live Session @ 9:40 -  ZEARN M4 L 20","aos":null,"aos_user":null,"aos_ass":null,"aos_work":null,"aos_assId":null,"c_id":"xxx","c_accountId":"xxx","c_enrollmentTermId":"xxx","c_name":"MATH 5 - xxx - 02","c_courseWorkflowState":"available","e_id":"xxx","e_courseId":"xxx","e_courseSectionId":"xxx","cs_sisSourceId":"xxx~xxx","u_id":"xxx","u_name":"xxx xxx","edd_assignmentId":null,"edd_userId":null,"edd_effectiveDueDate":null,"et_id":"xxx","et_name":"2022\/2023 S1 S2","et_startAt":"2022-08-04T05:01:00.000Z","et_endAt":"2023-05-23T04:59:00.000Z","et_valueGradingPeriodGroupId":"xxx","acc_id":"xxx","acc_name":"Elementary Math","acc_parentAccount":"xxx","really_dueAT":"2023-01-26T05:59:59Z","YearWeek":"202304","s_id":"xxx","s_excused":"false","s_assignmentId":"xxx","s_gradingPeriodId":"xxx","s_submission_type":"basic_lti_launch","s_workflowState":"graded","s_attempt":"1"}
```

column names and data were altered to protect data but the structure remains intact...
any insight would be greatly appreciated....

I have many other jobs that are in the same realm as this.... this file is quite large 1.5 gigs but it's not a timeout error... so I am lost

Comment: Format JSON before posting. Use a tool like `jq`. There is nothing wrong with the JSON you posted for line 1127. Problems like this are easy to solve. Break the file in half and test both halves. Repeat until you have the one section that fails.

Comment: I thank you @JohnHanley for your input it helped me solve my problem:
I was/am using `BCP` to do my conversion to `NDJSON` and using the `FOR JSON` along w/ `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` and unfortunately one of the unforeseen issues was that some `"` double quotes were not being picked up in the /escape queue I had to convert the troublesome column(varchar()) to `CAST([a_title]AS TEXT) AS a_title` for it to work...
addition info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/solve-common-issues-with-json-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Also I will leave this here for any other troubled soul when converting to NDJSON using `“` character is not escaped.... And furthermore is treaded as a `"` I used `REPLACE(a_title,'“', '')` in the BCP function for those if multiple weird issues you can use `replace(replace(replace(col, '$', ''), '£', ''), 'n/a', '')` more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/23218722/12017123