# SQL obtain only the numerical values from a varchar (Substring)

Tags: mysql, sql, substring, varchar, patindex

I have this varchar field;

```
Substrg
--------
38-40week
8month
7
40
38-40week
```

I would like to obtain only numbers for example:

```
38-40
8
7
40
38-40
```

I tried with this but it doesn't work...:

```
select SUBSTRING(Substrg, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Substrg), LEN(Substrg))
```

How can I do? Thanks

Comment: `PATINDEX()` is a SQL Server function but your question is tagged MySQL.  What database are you really using?  Also, when did an embedded `-` become a numeric character?

Comment: If it is SQL Server see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636045/t-sql-strip-all-non-alpha-and-non-numeric-characters using `select dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(fld, '%[^-0-9]%')`

Comment: You can extend mysql to make it support regular expressions, take a look at [this](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp) for more information

Answer (score 3):

```
select  replace ('38-40week', SUBSTRING('38-40week', PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', '38-40week'), 
LEN('38-40week')),'')
```