# Searching on telephone numbers with different formatting

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table where we store telephone numbers. These numbers are stored in a `VARCHAR(200)`. But are in different formats, for example:

```
040-1551515
(073) 614 53 97
+31884637222
```

I would like to search on the non numeric stripped string of this table. So if my search value would be '`0736145397`' it would match the '`(073) 614 53 97`'. Is this even possible?

Ideally it would be best if we would convert them all to one format but this is not gonna happen soon.

Comment: Use triggers to format the numbers at INSERT/UPDATE, and the search will become easier. (Until then, create a function that returns the number on the wanted format, use it when comparing numbers. You can later re-use that one when creating triggers.)

Comment: Use the UDF here: [T-SQL strip all non-alpha and non-numeric characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636045/t-sql-strip-all-non-alpha-and-non-numeric-characters) with `where dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(tel_no, '%[^0-9]%') = '0123456'` or **better** use a computed column/trigger to add normalized numbers using the UDF or client logic.

Comment: According to this, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx, you might be able to use `where phoneNumber like [numbers go here].  If not, maybe the patindex function is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Although ineligant, you can use `REPLACE` to strip characters from the phone number column in your `WHERE` clause, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #DemoTable (number VARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO #DemoTable (number) VALUES ('040-1551515'), ('(073) 614 53 97'), ('+31884637222')

SELECT  *
  FROM  #DemoTable
  WHERE (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(number, '-', ''), '+', ''), ' ', ''), '(', ''), ')', '') = '0736145397')

DROP TABLE #DemoTable
```

You would need to add a new `REPLACE` for each character you wish to remove.

As I said, ineligant, but if you only have a few characters to exclude this will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

select Try this

```
select phon_no from table
where replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_no,' ',''),'(',''),')',''),'+','')='0736145397'
```

However you can use another column that has phone numbers with no formatting so that you can use that column for searching

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` a lot to solve the problem:

```
where replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(tnumber, ' ', ''
                                             ), '(', ''
                                     ), ')', ''
                              ), '-', ''
                      ), '+', ''
             ) = '0736145397'
```

If you cannot change the data itself, you can consider adding a "cleaned" number as a computed column.  Something like:

```
alter table t add CleanNumber as (
              replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(tnumber, ' ', ''
                                                     ), '(', ''
                                             ), ')', ''
                                      ), '-', ''
                              ), '+', ''
                     ) )
```

Then the query would just be:

```
where CleanNumber = '0736145397'
```

Answer (score 0):

We can Replace function for it ..

```html
create table phonenumber (number varchar(200))
insert into phonenumber values('123456')
insert into phonenumber values('+555555')
insert into phonenumber values('77(123)989')

select replace(replace(number,'(',''),')','') formatednumber ,* from phonenumber with(nolock)
where replace(replace(number,'(',''),')','') ='77123989'
```

Thanks