# select statement that matches values without taking non-alphanumeric characters into account

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

In my database table i have a column with the name `item_name`. Some of the values look like below:

```
**Item_Name**
What's UP
Yahoo!!...
Alpha!@3568Numberic`;'"
```

Basically i am trying to convey that the values have non alpha numeric characters in them.

I want my sql statement to return values that match a row without taking the non-aplhanumeric characters into account.

For Example:

```
select *
from mutable
where item_name = 'whats up' or 'alpha3568numeric'
```

This SQL statement should return 2 rows:

```
What's UP
Alpha!@3568Numberic`;'"
```

Comment: what if the characters are jumbled? is it also ok if I say `pu` it should also return `What's UP`?

Comment: no.`pu` should not return anything. all alphanumeric characters should be present and their order must match

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to strip all non alphanumeric characters in your column and return the output string, just like this: [T-SQL strip all non-alpha and non-numeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636045/t-sql-strip-all-non-alpha-and-non-numeric-characters) [you'll have to change that to include 0-9 as well]

Then use in your where clause something like:

```
where lower(RemoveNonAlphaCharacters(item_name))like '%whats up%' or 
lower(RemoveNonAlphaCharacters(item_name))like '%alpha3568numeric%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
from mutable
where SOUNDEX(item_name) = SOUNDEX('whats up') or
SOUNDEX(item_name) = SOUNDEX('alpha3568numeric')
```