# Creating a SQL view and removing numbers + and () från result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a view v_purchasereport and gathering information from the PO table (Purchaseorders) and from the NAME column I want only the alphabeths AND "-" included as in our country you can have two part names with a "-" in between. No numbers nor other characters to be included in the view's name column.

In the PO.name column it can be: Mike Matthews +8012345678 or Matt Phillips (+8012345678)

And I want the v_purchasereport.name result to be Mike Matthews or Matt Phillips

Hope you can help! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: **Consumable** sample data, expect results, and, very **importantly**, *your* attempts will help us help you. T-SQL's forté, however, is not String Manipulation

Comment: Do these answer your question? [How to strip all non-alphabetic characters from string in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1007697/2029983), [How to remove non alphanumeric characters in SQL without creating a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54953097/2029983). [T-SQL strip all non-alpha and non-numeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9636045/2029983)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use:

```
select left(name, patindex('% [(+]%', name + ' (') - 1)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0186a71b3b64e2c5bd38ad1c89c04799) is a db<>fiddle.

You can easily add additional splitter characters in the pattern.  Or simply use `' [^-a-zA-Z]` if you wanted any non-alpha character.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @name nvarchar(max)='Mike Matthews +8012345678'  

--DECLARE @name nvarchar(max)='Matt Phillips (+8012345678)'

SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN CHARINDEX('(', @name) > 0
      THEN LTRIM(LEFT(@name, CHARINDEX('(', @name)-1))
    WHEN CHARINDEX('+', @name) >0
      THEN LTRIM(LEFT(@name, CHARINDEX('+', @name)-1))
    ELSE  @name 
  END AS name
```

Link: https://rextester.com/UEZHB46672

Comment: Hi, I would need a generic that works on both '+' and '(' as the name list is quite long, how can I do that?

Comment: @J33, Now see my code again. I think it will help you.